# How to Handle Back Button on Android

Tags: java, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to make a app with WebView ,and i want to exit app if WebView Back History is finished.

This is the scenario what i want ,gif animation :

[image]

my Project Structure (my code):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package = "com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup = "true"
        android:icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label = "@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl = "true"
        android:theme = "@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name = ".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

layout: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:gravity = "center"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    tools:context = ".MainActivity"
    android:orientation = "vertical">
   <WebView
       android:id = "@+id/web_view"
       android:layout_width = "match_parent"
       android:layout_height = "match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

java: MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        WebView web_view = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        web_view.requestFocus();
        web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            web_view.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        }
        web_view.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });

        web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

i found the code here [How to Control Back Button in Android Scenario 3](https://vlemon.com/blog/android/how-to-control-back-button-in-android/)

I tried to make working my code and the code from that site , but it give me ERROR-S on Adobe Studio ,

what i tried is:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        WebView web_view = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        web_view.requestFocus();
        web_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            web_view.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        }
        web_view.loadUrl("https://alltrafficcams.com/");
        web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

        });

        web_view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress < 100) {
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                if (progress == 100) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(webView.canGoBack())
            {
                webView.goBack();
            }
            else
            {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

    }
}
```

Pleas can somone help me to make my code working. thank you

Comment: `onBackPressed` should be outside concrete, pay attention to scope of the methods.

Comment: still it give me a error :( pleas can you paste me full code thanks in advance